# Selection Sort Implementation

Tags: c#

I'm not really sure what's wrong with the implementation I have. How would I fix this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
namespace SelectionSort

{
  class Program
  {

    static void algorithm(int[] to_sort)        
    {
        int bufor;

        for (int i = 0; i < to_sort.Length; i++)
        {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < to_sort.Length; j++)
            {

                if (to_sort[i] >= to_sort[j])     
                {                           
                    bufor = to_sort[i];         
                    to_sort[i] = to_sort[j];
                    to_sort[j] = bufor;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        int[] to_sort = new int[100];   

        Console.WriteLine("");

        for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++)       
        {


            Console.Write(to_sort[i] + " ");    
        }

        Console.WriteLine("");

        algorithm(to_sort);
        Console.WriteLine("\n");
        Console.WriteLine("Sorted list:");
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)        
        {
            Console.Write(to_sort[i] + " ");
        }
        Console.Read();
    }
  }
}
```

This produces the following output:

```
Original list: 00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
               00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
Sorted list: 000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
              00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

It looks like my array (int[] to_sort) was empty, am I right? How can I get this:

```
Original list: 123456789....100
Sorted list: 123456789...100
```

Comment: Where would you have filled it?

Comment: your original list is all 0s, so its already sorted.

Comment: What is the problem here?  Are you really asking why your list of zeros isn't sorting correctly?  How *should* it sort?

Comment: I want to have the following output:

Original list: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 .... 100
Sorted list: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 ..... 100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest and shortest way you can initialize an array of sequential numbers is like this:

```
int[] to_sort = Enumerable.Range(1, 100).ToArray();
```

What you have will just allocate the array and fill it with the default value for `int`, which is `0`:

```
int[] to_sort = new int[100];
```

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you originate from the C++ world where initializing an array does not mean the array is "*cleaned*" (the data that happened to be located at the allocated memory remains untouched), but in C# if you initialize an array like:

```
int[] to_sort = new int[100];
```

It means you construct an array where **every element is set to `default(T)`** with `T` the type. For an `int` that is `0` (for objects it is `null`, etc.). So you just constructed an array filled with zeros.

You can however for instance fill it with random numbers like:

```
Random rand = new Random();

for(int i = 0; i < to_sort.Length; i++) {
    to_sort[i] = rand.Next(0,1000);
}
```

**EDIT**

Based on your comment, you want to fill it with the positions, you can do this like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < to_sort.Length; i++) {
    to_sort[i] = i+1;
}
```